# crypto.createECDH is not getting added with webpack

Tags: node.js, webpack, public-key-encryption, secret-key, ecdh

I want to use createECDH function provided by crypto module in nodejs. I downloaded all the dependencies. Webpack does not add createECDH function in my resultant javascript files. How to use createECDH function of crypto available in node.

it adds number of functions like createCipher, createDechiper, createDiffihelman, listCiphers, getCiphers etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly you're using old version of crypto lib. According to [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html), ECDH class was added in v0.11.14, later than the rest of functions you mentioned.

It would be nice to see your code.